G/T in Satellite Communications
G/T is an important metric in satellite communications, where G refers to the antenna gain, and T refers to the receiver noise temperature; and in a matched system, noise power =K.T/Hz where K is Boltzmann constant.
Can one express inband interference and inband intermodulation power by a noise temperature  as well? Probably by dividing their corresponding power density by Boltzmann constant, and thus include it in the G/T calculation or is noise temperature related solely to thermal noise power and only thermal noise?

You can, if that's helpful for your modelling. In general, you need to be careful: a narrowband interferer might be less of a problem than a white noise signal of identical power would be (because it can be adaptively filtered out at little loss of signal, or if you come from an information theory side, because it has less differential entropy), and an intermodulation product can be worse, as it might have identical statistics as the signal of interest and thus might "hurt" your system by confusing e.g. carrier recovery.
So, you can do that, if you can model these signal components as having the same effect as white noise.

But then Boltzmann constant has nothing to do with IMD , wouldn't dividing an IMD power by Boltzmann constant something like mixing apples with oranges? Also we know that BER performance for a certain SNR is not the same as the BER for a certain SDR( signal to distortion ratio) , so I am not sure if this can be done from a purely scientific or academic  point of view, no?

My answer addresses exactly that!
